# Find the radius of convergence of the power series expanded about the indicated point

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I missed a lecture last class and I have absolutely no idea how to even start this. I understood how to do radius of convergence normally perfectly fine but my book isn't helping me at all with power series, and i've already tried using my calc textbook for help. I am going to office hours tomorrow to get help but I would like to get some of my HW done so I don't go to his office and say "Hey I know absolutely nothing, show me how to do this".

a) $\frac{1}{z-1}$ about $z = i$.

For this one, I am observing that there will be a singularity at $|z|$, but in the book they do stuff with just filling in bad points and i'm not sure where to go from here.

b) $\frac{z - i}{z^3 - z}$ about $z = 2i$.

Comment: If you need to expand $f(z)$ in powers of $z-a$, then expand $f(z+a)$ in powers of $z$ and the coefficients of this are the coefficients of the original. For (a). $f(z+i)=\frac{1}{z+i-1}=\frac{1}{i-1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{1-i}}=\frac{1}{i-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{(1-i)^n}$. Here we used that $\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$.

Comment: Most of the series expansions can be computed by the tableau method. You have a table of a few basic series expansions and try to reduce others to those. For example, the binomial formula $(1+z)^r=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{r}{n}z^n$, of which $(1-z)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$ is a particular case, will help you compute the series expansions of all rational functions. The idea is to decompose them into simple fractions and then use the binomial theorem on them.

Comment: Are you saying that I can use the identity 1/1-z = ∑∞n=0 z^n can be used for this one? We just say that z = 1-z, and n = -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{z-1} &= \frac{1}{z-i-(1-i)} \\
&=-\frac{1}{1-i} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{z-i}{1-i}} \\
&=-\frac{1}{1-i} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-i)^n}(z-i)^{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now it is clear the the radius of convergence is
$$
\begin{aligned}
R &= \frac{1}{\limsup \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{|1-i|^{n}}}} \\
&= |1-i| \\
&= \sqrt{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Can you use this method to find the answer for part $(b)$?

Edit:

To justify the first equality, simply add and subtract $i$ in the denominator. Then, from the first line to the second, I factored out a $-(1-i)$ from the denominator. The next step is the use the fact that $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n}$ for $|z|<1$. Instead of $z$, here we are dealing with $\frac{z-i}{1-i}$. Finally, to find the radius of convergence, use the fact that $\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}$, where $a_{n} = \frac{1}{(1-i)^{n}}$.

Comment: I understand the process you are doing but there are a few steps I missing the fundamentals of. On your second line (the what appears to be a partial fraction?) i'm not sure how you got there. But then for the rest, I think you put it into the form f(z) = sum(Ak * (z-z0)^k), and then from there you use the identity 1/1-z = sum(z^n) and then use the root test?

Comment: What you say seems right to me. I see you've accepted my answer, but I can add more information if you like.

Comment: I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm sorry, i'm new to this website i'm not sure how to use it correctly haha.

Comment: I've edited the question to add a little more detail. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now! Much appreciated